# Disable truncate listview header jquery mobile for long text (single word)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile listview . Currently the header of the list view truncates, and the text ends with a "...".  I would like to disable this behavior and show the complete text.  I ran into a few solutions but none of them work for a single word. i.e, text without white space, for example an email address does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7q8JT/)**

The CSS you are looking for is `word-wrap:break-word;`

```
ul li h2 {
    white-space: normal !important;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

For more browser support you could try:

```
ul li h2{
    white-space: pre !important;           /* CSS 2.0 */
    white-space: pre-wrap !important;      /* CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: pre-line !important;      /* CSS 3.0 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap !important;     /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap !important;   /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; /* Mozilla */
    white-space: -hp-pre-wrap !important;  /* HP Printers */
    word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5+ */
}
```