# Jquery Mobile - Header button text truncated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm building a Phonegap web application, using Jquery Mobile. 
I have a header in my page with a title and a custom button on the left. The HTML code is something like this:

```
 <div data-role="page" id="otsTopPage" data-theme="a"> 
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
            <h1 id="ots_top_h1"></h1>
            <a id="aboutButton" href="common/about.html" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog"></a>
        </div> 

        <div data-role="content">
            <fieldset class="ui-grid-b" id="TopGrid">
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-id="navBar" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="navbar">
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div>
 </div>
```

And the content is generated by a jquery file.

Both the title and button display fine in the browser, but when I build the application the button text is truncated like so:
[image: press view image to see full size]

The same thing happens in another page that contains two buttons:

```
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
            <a id="tpoShow_back_button" href="#" data-rel="back" 
                data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
            <h1 id="formPageTitle" ><span id="tpo_show_object_types"></span></h1>
            <a href="map.html" id="tpoShow_map_button" >Map</a>
        </div>
```

The back button displays properly, but the Map button is truncated.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682673/disable-truncate-listview-header-jquery-mobile-for-long-text-single-word

Comment: Interestingly, this solution worked for my phone but it still doesnt display correctly when I try it in the Bluestacks emulator.
I'll keep this open a little longer while I try it in other devices/platforms